# How to set shared global variables between two files

Tags: python, global-variables

I have some files with the following structures. I would like to set `device` in `train.py` so the change reflects in `eval.py` but it doesn't and it probably execute `common.py` independently. I prefer not to import none common files in each other. However, I may import `eval` in `train` to do evaluation after train.

What is the solution or best practice for my scenario?

common.py

```
device = "cpu"
```

train.py

```
from common import *
from eval import *
import click
@click.command()
@click.argument("dev", type=str)
def train(dev):
   global device
   device = dev
   eval()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    train() # it prints "cpu"
```

eval.py

```
from common import *

def eval():
   print(device) # I expect to have 'cuda' here
```

Now

```
$ python train.py cuda
$ cpu
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this "just work", I think you need to change `common.py` like so:

```py
global device = "cpu"
```

I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to achieve, but seems like a default value for `click` might be what you ACTUALLY want to do.

However, Python's FAQ recommends that [the canonical way to solve this is with a config file](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules).

Regarding "best practices", a few other things could be improved here:

1. [`eval` is a Python keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval), so you should really avoid using it as a file name.
2. Star imports (`from x import *`) aren't the best, as well, as they might cause name-clash issues. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad) for details.

Comment: Thanks, however you suggestion raise a syntax error, even if I declare it like `global device` and in next line `device ="cpu"` it doesn't have any effect. But I agree that I may not need to declare it in `common.py`, but I kept the question for a senario that is needed.